# WordPress page does not show content, did before

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 4.6.1

On this page http://jonesdivorcelaw.com/about-us/our-team/ there is no content.
There is a cached version via google - http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AVM9C4hxaX0J:jonesdivorcelaw.com/about-us/our-team/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca that is how it should look.

There is a page created called our-team which has no content.

Somehow the page magically used to pull the partners, associates and staff onto the page, but again the page has no content defined in it when I try and edit it.

We use a plugin called CPTUI which has post types, 3 of the post types are partners, associates and staff, but where do I tell WordPress to display them on the Our Team page?

Comment: Content does never magically appear haha. Can you confirm that the content-types still have the posts?

Comment: @Kevinvhengst how do I confirm that? And if the content isn't magically appearing, where does it say in WP Admin to show them on the our-team page?

Comment: Well, if the content-types are created, there should be 3 tabs in the sidebar of the wordpress admin environment called `Partners`, `Associates` and `staff`. Check those tabs if they have any posts.

Comment: Yes they do, there are 2 partners, 3 associates, 4 staff

Comment: Ok, so we've eliminated the possibility that the content was just not there. Then check what template is being used on the `our-team` page. Maybe the template got switched by accident.

Comment: The template being used is called page.php - I do not have the ability to edit that template, or switch it I believe. That same template is used on other pages and the content appears fine for those pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125128/discussion-between-kevinvhengst-and-andrewb).